# Decode a URL string encoded compliant with RFC 3986 to json with golang

Tags: go

I have a string which is URL-encoded compliant with RFC 3986. I want to decode this string to JSON.

Is there an API call to get this done? I did not find any in https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.String

I got a string as the response of one of the API call of aws service. It's described here in docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/…. As described here I am getting aws Policy as URL-encoded compliant with RFC 3986. I want to convert it to normal JSON form.

Comment: Give an example of a string and what you expect to get when decoding it. Are you receiving the encoded string in an HTTP request handler?

Comment: Nope I got this as the response of one of the API call of aws service. It's described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetAccountAuthorizationDetails.html. As described I am getting aws Policy as URL-encoded compliant with RFC 3986. I want to convert it to normal json form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `url.QueryUnEscape`  to decode the string and then use `json.Marshal` to convert to a json

```
package main

import (
    "net/url"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age int `json:"age"`
}

func main() {
    s := "%7B%22name%22%3A%22user1%22%2C%22age%22%3A30%7D" // URL encoded value

    in, err := url.QueryUnescape(s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("query escaped %s \n", in)
    var u User
    // unmarshalling
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(in),&u)
    fmt.Printf("username : %s,  age %d \n", u.Name, u.Age)

    //marshalling
    bytes , err := json.Marshal(in)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
}
```